# Understanding unsigned char left rotation in C

Tags: c, arrays, rotation, bit-manipulation, unsigned

I needed to do a left rotate of an unsigned char array by 1 using C. I found the folowing code on the internet that I am having a hard time to fathom. I never thought it would be so complicated (at least it is, for me). Can someone please help me understand exactly what's going on with the code here?

```
/* accept an unsigned char array, with size and rotate it left by one 1 position*/

static void rotate_left( unsigned char * input, int size)
{
    int i, carry_back= 0;

    if(input[size-1] & (1<<(CHAR_BIT - 1)))
    {
        carry_back = 1;
    }

    for(i= size-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        unsigned char carry = 0;

        if(i!= 0 && (input[i-1] & (1<<(CHAR_BIT - 1))))
        {
            carry = 1;
        }
        input[i] <<= 1;
        input[i] |= carry;

    }

    if(carry_back == 1)
    {
        input[0] |= 0x01;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try stepping through it with a pen and paper.  Or perhaps stepping through with a debugger.

Comment: On most systems, `CHAR_BIT` is 8, so `1<<(CHAR_BIT - 1)` is the same as `1<<7` which is `0x80`. In other words, it's a bit mask for the most significant bit of an `unsigned char`.

Comment: by: *rotate it left by one 1 position*, do you mean to rotate by one bit or by one array entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code rotates left by one bit a *sequence* of size `size` of unsigned `char`s, represented by `input` pointer. The sequence is arranged back-to-front, as in [*little endian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) systems.

In order to do that you start from the back of the sequence, and work your way left, each time extracting the most significant bit to shift, or "carry", into the prior `unsigned char`. The extraction of the most significant bit is done using this formula: `input[i] & (1<<(CHAR_BIT - 1))` which amounts to checking the bit by "masking" it using bitwise `&` operator. Each individual `unsigned char` is also shifted left, with its most significant bit dropped.

As the final step the algorithm pushes the most significant bit of the last `unsigned char`, as represented by `carry_back`, into the least significant bit of the initial `unsigned char`, thus completing the rotation.

> Why are we checking `input[i-1]` in `i!=0 && (input[i-1] & (1<<CHAR_BIT -1)))`?

Because the sequence is arranged in such a way that the next `unsigned char` to the left of position `i` is located at position `i+1`, so `i-1` is actually to the right of position `i`.

> why are we doing an OR between `input[i]` and the carry at the end?

We do it to complete the rotation, making the shift circular.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I still don't understand the following part clearly, though I feel like I am almost there with your explanation - if(i!=0 && (input[i-1] & (1<<CHAR_BIT -1))))  {carry =1;} input[i] << 1; input[i] |= carry;} Why are we checking input[i-1] here? Also, why are we doing an OR between input[i] and the carry at the end?

Comment: Thanks. That makes it pretty clear. So, going by that, the following version should also work- what do you think?                                                                            
 static void rotate_left( unsigned char * input, int size)
{
    int carry = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = size - 1; i >=0; i--) {
        int next = (input[i] & 1) ? 0x80: 0;
        input[i] = carry | (input[i]<<1);
        carry = next;
    }
    
}

Comment: @Subzero The problem with your loop is that it is not processing the `carry_back` bit. To do it right set `carry` to `1` when the most significant bit of the last byte is set.